# Randomizing a sample by selected groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random, sample

In my dataset, 90 people (samples) must each play two types of game, of a total of four types: `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `W`. I would like to randomize in R which games each person will play, as well as the game order, so that it follows this way:

| UA | First game | Second game |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | Game X | Game W |
| Person 2 | Game W | Game Y |
| Person 3 | Game Z | Game W |

Thus, each game must be played by the same number of people (*i.e.*, 30 people per game), and game `W` must be played by everyone. Is there a simple way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create vector that contains 30 reps of games X, Y, Z
2. create random permutation of that vector
3. to each game add game W
4. permute each game pair

```
games <- t(
  apply(
    data.frame(
      first_game = sample(rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 30), 90),
      second_game = "W"
    ),
    1,
    function(x) sample(x, 2)
  )
)

games <- cbind(paste("pearson", 1:90), games)
colnames(games) <- c("UA" ,"first_game", "second_game")
games <- as.data.frame(games)
```

Comment: Much obliged! It worked perfectly!